# Bitcoin - JavaScript function to return the current BTC exchange rate

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

I'm looking to write a JavaScript function that will return the current BTC/USD exchange rate. I've done some research, but I just want something simple. It won't be used server-side for calculating values (obvious security implications), but just as a convenience for my users. I have 2 text fields, and when the user changes one of the values, it will update the other field.

Here is my code so far:

```
var getBTCRate = function(){ /* code here */ };

var btcprice = getBTCRate();

// update the BTC value as the USD value is updated
$("#usdvalue").keyup(function(ev){
    var usdvalue = $("#usdvalue").val();
    $("#btcvalue").val(usdvalue / btcprice);
});

// update the USD value as the BTC value is updated
$("#btcvalue").keyup(function(ev){
    var btcvalue = $("#btcvalue").val();
    $("#usdvalue").val(btcvalue * btcprice);
});
```

Plain and simple. In my research I haven't been able to find something that will do this, only a bunch of confusing APIs. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDITED** to fix a mistake in the code.

**EDITED AGAIN** to fix the position of the function declaration. Thanks to @RobG for pointing this out.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I'm unable to find a function that does what I need it to, and am curious if anyone knows of such a function. It's pretty basic functionality I see on almost every Bitcoin exchange, but can't seem to find a way of implementing it.

Comment: The [**CoinMarketCap API**](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) returns JSON.

Comment: @ObsidianAge How would this be implemented? It gives way more information than I need.

Comment: @RobG that was a mistake, the final code would use the global variable

Comment: @RobG Thank you, I will certainly fix that in the final code. My main consern here is with the actual contents of such a function.

Comment: Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/mug62cuf/

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to use JQuery load like this

```
$.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=btc+value', function(p) {
  console.log(p);
});
```

but cross-origin rules stopped me.
Now, you can pay for a service that has an API, but I wanted to do it without having to pay. What I ended up doing is a server based solution. I use PowerBasic for my back end, with the SocketTools Library.

```
#COMPILE EXE
#DIM ALL
#Include "pbcgi.inc"
#Include "C:\bas_src\socketTools\v9.5\inc\cstools9.inc"     

Function PBMain () As Long         
    Local btc As String         
    Local html As String   

    html= httpGet("https://www.google.com/search?q=btc+value")      

    ' filter out just the current BTC value
    ' by looking for what is between the words "Bitcoin =" and "United States Dollar"
    btc=Remain$(html,"Bitcoin =")     
    btc=Extract$(btc,"United States Dollar")
    btc=Trim$(btc)

    writeCGI "{"+jsonPad("btc")+":"+jsonPad(btc)+","+jsonPad("error")+":"+jsonPad("0")+"}"


END FUNCTION

'================================================================
' retrieve the page and return it as a string
Function httpGet(ByVal URL As String) As String

    If IsFalse( HttpInitialize($CSTOOLS9_LICENSE_KEY) ) Then
        Function="unable to init socket library"
        Exit Function
    End If         

  Local hClient      As Dword
  Local lpszURL      As STRINGZ * 4096
  Local lpszBuffer   As STRINGZ * 100000
  Local httpContents As String
  Local httpPort     As Long
  Local httpOptions  As Dword
  Local nResult      As Long

  If LCase$(Trim$(Left$(URL, 8))) = "https://" Then
     httpPort    = 443
     httpOptions = %HTTP_OPTION_SECURE Or %HTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT
  Else
     httpPort    = 80
     httpOptions = %HTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT
  End If

  lpszURL = URL & Chr$(0)

  hClient = HttpConnect(lpszURL, _
                        httpPort, _
                        %HTTP_TIMEOUT, _
                        httpOptions, _
                        %HTTP_VERSION_10)

  If hClient = %INVALID_CLIENT Then
      Function = "Could not connect to: " & URL
      Exit Function
  End If

  HttpSetEncodingType(hClient, %HTTP_ENCODING_NONE)
  nResult = HttpGetText(hClient, lpszURL, lpszBuffer, 100000)

  If nResult = %HTTP_ERROR Then
      Function = "Error retrieving file."+Str$(nResult)
  Else    
      ' success
      httpContents = lpszBuffer     
      Function =httpContents    
  End If

  Call HttpDisconnect(hClient)        
  HttpUninitialize()

End Function
'================================================================


' pad string for json return
Function jsonPad(jstr As String) As String       
  Local i As Long

  Replace Chr$(10) With " " In jstr    
  Replace Chr$(13) With " " In jstr    
  Replace "\" With "\\" In jstr  
  Replace $Dq With "\"+$Dq In jstr   

  For i = 0 To 9
    Replace Chr$(i) With " " In jstr
  Next       

  Function=$Dq+Trim$(jstr)+$Dq               


End Function
```

On my web page, I call it using AJAX

```
function showBTC(){

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../cgi/btcGet.exe",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){       

            if(json.error !== "0" ){
                console.log( json.error );
                return;
            }

            $("#btcValue").html( "current BTC value $"+json.btc+"<br><br>" );
    }
  });   
}
```

I know that seems like a "too specific" answer, but it's how I do it.

**EDIT 5/11/2020:**
there is a Bitcoin API found at [coindesk.com](https://www.coindesk.com/coindesk-api) which greatly simplifies this process.

Answer (score -1):

```
const api = 'https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/local/ticker/short?crypto=BTC&fiat=USD'
$.get(api, p => {
  document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(p, null, 2)
});
```

Result

```
{
  "BTCUSD": {
    "ask": 3594.5649555077953,
    "timestamp": 1550284932,
    "bid": 3591.715961836563,
    "last": 3592.745617344171,
    "averages": {
      "day": 3583.13243402
    }
  }
}
```

So take your pick `p.BTCUSD.ask // or bid or last`

[demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/x4JZddd3EeCf7Ns2?open=lib%2Fscript.js)